# How to used brands attribute set on top reating product on show home page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

How to used brands attribute set on top reating product on show home page? used to brands attribute set and refelect all top product show on home page .

Comment: magento2 doesn't know brands. so "without any extention" is impossible. you will need to write your own code or install a extension to achieve this